# Evaluation control inside Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, compile, hold

I have the following function

```
cTestEvalControl = 
  With[{eq = 
     Unevaluated[{{Flatten[a + 5 b^2] d + Flatten[a^2*b + 3 b*a] c, 
        Flatten[a*b^2] c + 
         Flatten[a^2*b] d}, {Flatten[a*b^3 + 5 b^2] c + 
         Flatten[a^2*b^4 + 12 b*a^2] c, 
        Flatten[4 a*b^2 + 3 a] c + Flatten[a^2*b^2] d}}]}, 
   Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 2}, {c, _Real, 2}, {d, _Real, 
      2}}, eq, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    Parallelization -> True]];
```

some small example with it

```
v1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2}]; m1 = 
 RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]; m2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]; m3 = 
 RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];

cTestEvalControl[v1, m1, m2, m3]

{{{{2.27262, 2.56534, 2.07663, 1.60572}, {0.59353, 0.132561, 0.401489,
 0.114946}, {0.657416, 0.388311, 0.43386, 0.414723}, {0.903638, 
0.686363, 0.38627, 0.749547}}, {{0.169533, 0.236441, 0.178987, 
0.206864}, {0.0235736, 0.00447615, 0.0158849, 
0.00488492}, {0.019912, 0.0155357, 0.0189165, 
0.0178772}, {0.0257693, 0.0501467, 0.0207543, 
0.0225687}}}, {{{1.51258, 2.92861, 2.03442, 3.42816}, {0.293951, 
0.197261, 0.209069, 0.00361905}, {0.220347, 0.293738, 0.39574, 
0.3694}, {0.310412, 1.25446, 0.457183, 0.29725}}, {{0.871715, 
1.62655, 1.13975, 1.85736}, {1.26437, 0.847259, 0.899176, 
0.0160615}, {0.287964, 0.380763, 0.512416, 0.478373}, {0.211849, 
0.832085, 0.304355, 0.201926}}}}
```

I really need the evaluation inside the `Flatten` to happen before the `Flatten`.

Is this the best way to do this?

In reallity `eq` will be a large matrix, say 100x100, of symbolic expressions, in which I want to plug in numerical values to evaluate it. In total there are 50 different arguments that I have to plug in to get a numerical value for the whole matrix `eq`. 
So each expression inside `eq` has the structure of `Flatten[longAndNasty]*variable`. Each `longAndNasty` (it is different for every expression) will be thousands of terms long, consisting of various combinations of these 50 arguments. Some of these arguments are scalars (like the constants 5, 3, 12 and so on in my example), some are vectors of length 'N' (like the `a` in the example) and some are matrices of size `NxN` (like `b` in my example). The `variable` thing is a an arguemnt that I plug in, like all the previous things I have described,  but it is of size `N^2xN^2`, hence why I need to `Flatten` `longAndNasty`.

My non-compiled code uses an `Association` which I pass to a `KeyValueMap` that basically applies `Flatten[Value/.{ReplacementRules}]*BigMatrix` and then I `Total` over all the `Keys`. I am looking for a speed up through `Compile`.

Comment: I really do not get the purpose of this question. I do not see any symbolic matrices here and the job that `cTestEvalControl` is doing can be performed _faster_ with ordinary vectorized code like `Flatten[v1 m1^2] m2 + Flatten[v1^2 m1] m3`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In reallity `eq` is a matrix of expressions, say 100x100, whereby each expression is something long and nasty that has the form of `Flatten[longAndNasty]*c`, whereby c is to be replaced with a big matrix and `longAndNasty` is a symbolic expression in which I want to plug in vectors and matrices.

Comment: `c` is with dimensions `(nx^2) by (nx^2)`, whereas the vectors and matrices in `longAndNasty` are with sizes `(nx)` and `(nx) by (nx)`, respectively. Hence, flattening the `longAndNasty` bit gives you something that can multiply the `c`

Comment: How are we supposed to understand it without a complete minimal example?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have given the most minimal example? Is it too minimal? Do you want me to add more terms to the expressions? Or shall I make `eq` a matrix? The applied solution should work irrespective of the tensor rank of `eq`, shouldn't it?

Comment: As of now your example presents a snippet of code that can be handled much easier without compilation (with `Flatten[v1 m1^2] m2 + Flatten[v1^2 m1] m3`). So it is not even an _example_...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I updated my question. Is it clear what I want? I can't reall do `Flatten[v1 m1^2] m2 + Flatten[v1^2 m1] m3`, as I am not entering anything by hand, as my expressions are pages long. In my non-compiled code I do use `Flatten[expr/.Dispatch[rules]]*m` for each element of the matrix of expressions, but I want a faster way of doing this.